# How to query SQL Server Agent - all jobs's error message result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Question:** how to query SQL Server Agent - all jobs' error message result set

[image: image-20200814085131688]

Input:

```sql
select *
from [jobs's error masseage table]
where status = 'error' and date between '2020-05-01' and '2020-06-01'
```

Expected result:

```
jobname , runtime , status , message
xxx1 , 2020-05-03 , error , #)*)_(#_@$#
xxx2 , 2020-05-05 , error , #)*)_(#_@$#
....
```

What I've tried & know: I know `Job Activity Monitor` GUI form can do it, but it only contains last run as shown in this screenshot:

[image: image-20200814085609180]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched msdn and found [dbo.sysjobhistory (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobhistory-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) can do it

```sql
SELECT sj.name,
        sh.*
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory sh ON sj.job_id = sh.job_id
where run_status = 0 and run_date between '20200806' and '20200811'
order by run_date
```

[image: image-20200814100930197]

but it looks like only cotaining few days data.

[image: image-20200814100844574]